# Opening a modal from each row in table of Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue2 and Bootstrap-Vue. I have a table with data (I use `b-table`). I want to have "edit" option on each row in order to edit the table. This option (which is an icon of gear) will open a modal and display a view boxes. In my view I have:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table class="text-center" striped hover
     :items="items"
     :bordered=tableBordered
     :fields=tableFields
     :label-sort-asc=tableLabelSortAsc>
      <template #cell(view)="data">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="no-link" :href="data.item.url">
          <b-icon icon="eye-fill"/>
        </a>
      </template>
      <template #cell(edit)="data">
        <b-icon icon="gear-fill"/>
        <edit-info-modal :data="data"/>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import EditInfoModal from './EditInfoModal.vue';
  import { BIcon } from 'bootstrap-vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      'b-icon': BIcon,
      'edit-info-modal': EditInfoModal
    },
    data() {
      return {
        tableBordered: true,
        tableLabelSortAsc: "",
        tableFields: [
          { sortable: false, key: 'edit', label: 'edit' },
          { sortable: true,  key: 'comments', label: 'comments' },
          { sortable: false, key: 'view', label: 'view' }
        ],
        items: [
          {
            "comments": "test",
            "url": "some_url"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a.no-link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover.no-link {
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    cursor: pointer;  
}
</style>
```

It creates a table with three columns - the view column (with eye icon) which redirects to the url, the comments column and the edit column (with gear icon) which should open the modal.

Now, I'm trying to have the modal in a separated Vue file called `EditInfoModal`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
      <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { BModal } from 'bootstrap-vue';

export default {
  props: {
    data: Object
  },
  components: {
    'b-modal': BModal
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

First of all, it does not open the modal. Reading over the internet I noticed that I should add `isModalOpen` field and update it each time and then create the `watch` method. But here I have a modal for each row. What is the recommended way to keep track of the opened modal (only one is opened at any given time)?

Comment: I implemented same functionality with most of the feature. Checkout the repo https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue_crud_bootstrap . Hope it will helps you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Demo link https://jebasuthan.github.io/vue_crud_bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** install `BootstrapVue` package and references in `main.js`

```
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons);
```

**Step 2:** `App.vue` component

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-table
      class="text-center"
      striped
      hover
      :items="items"
      :bordered="tableBordered"
      :fields="tableFields"
      :label-sort-asc="tableLabelSortAsc">
      <template #cell(view)="data">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="no-link" :href="data.item.url">
          <b-icon icon="eye-fill" />
        </a>
      </template>
      <template #cell(edit)="data">
        <b-icon icon="gear-fill" @click.prevent="editTable(data)" />
      </template>
    </b-table>
    <edit-info-modal :data="data" :showModal="showModal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { BIcon, BTable } from "bootstrap-vue";
import EditInfoModal from "./components/EditInfoModal.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    "b-table": BTable,
    "b-icon": BIcon,
    "edit-info-modal": EditInfoModal,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tableBordered: true,
      tableLabelSortAsc: "",
      tableFields: [
        { sortable: false, key: "edit", label: "edit" },
        { sortable: true, key: "comments", label: "comments" },
        { sortable: false, key: "view", label: "view" },
      ],
      items: [
        {
          comments: "Vue CRUD Bootstrap app",
          url: "https://jebasuthan.github.io/vue_crud_bootstrap/",
        },
        {
          comments: "Google",
          url: "https://www.google.com/",
        },
      ],
      data: "",
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    editTable(data) {
      this.data = Object.assign({}, data.item);;
      this.showModal = true;
      // this.$root.$emit("edit-table", Object.assign({}, data));
      // this.$bvModal.show("modal-1");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
div {
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a.no-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover.no-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

**Step 3:** Child component `EditInfoModal.vue`

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <b-modal v-model="showModal" id="modal-1" title="Edit Table">
      <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
      <p>Comments: {{ data.comments }}</p>
      <p>
        URL: <a :href="data.url">{{ data.url }}</a>
      </p>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { BModal } from "bootstrap-vue";

export default {
  // data() {
  //   return {
  //     data: "",
  //     showModal: "",
  //   };
  // },
  props: ["data", "showModal"],
  components: {
    "b-modal": BModal,
  },
  // mounted() {
  //   this.$root.$on("edit-table", (data) => {
  //     this.data = data.item;
  //   });
  // },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

[DEMO Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-violet-m8d7h)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed solution. Is it possible to show to use `props` instead of  `$root/$emit`?

Comment: @vesii I updated the answer and kindly check and let me know

Comment: I see. So there is no option to display the `b-modal` without calling `this.$bvModal.show("modal-1");`? I though there will be a boolean flag `show-modal` which I pass to the `b-modal`.

Comment: @vesii yes you can do that with `v-model="showModal"`. I updated the demo link.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out. btw, I noticed that if you add a few more rows (add more blocks to `items`) and click one of the modals, it will open all of the modals. How to fix it?

Comment: @vesii I updated the answer and demo link too. Kindly validate and if my answers helps you please accept the answer and give a thumbs up!

Comment: @vesii Have you checked the code and is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. thanks again! Looks like when you try to re-open the same modal, it does not let you. I guess it has something to do with `close`.

Comment: @vesii I updated the demo link. Hope it will resolve all of your issues. Thank you.  if my answers helps you please accept the answer and give a thumbs up!

Comment: @vesii My solution works for you? or still facing issues?